# Automatically redirect to different page after session timeout in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

How to Automatically redirect to a different page when the session is expired?

Below is my startup.cs code.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();

        services.AddAuthentication(options => {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
             }).AddCookie(options =>
        {
            options.LoginPath = "/auth/signin";
            options.SlidingExpiration = true;
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);

        });

    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }



        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

I am able to redirect to login page if I click on a button or an Actionlink.
But I want to get redirected automatically to a different page(other than login page) when the session expires.
Could someone help me with this, please?

Comment: That's not how sessions work. First, sessions use sliding expirations, so as long as a user stays active, they'll never expire. If the user does become inactive long enough for the session expire (makes no further requests for the entire period of the life of the session), then the user still sends the session cookie back. When that particular session cannot be restored because it has expired it's the same as if no session existed at all previously. A new session is simply created and an new cookie sent to the user.

Comment: did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
  options.Cookie.Name = "auth_cookie";
            options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
            options.LoginPath = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.PathString("/Account/Login");
            options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/Login";
            options.ReturnUrlParameter = "/Account/Login";
            options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/AccessDenied";
            options.LogoutPath = "/Account/Logout";
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);//set it less for testing purpose
            // options.Events.OnRedirectToLogin
```

commment out the code the code Events.OnRedirectToLogin or OnRedirectToLogin this returns error code.
i think we can either display an Error 401 or 302 etc or redirect the user to the Login page.
Hope it helps